# Create a new CI server in 32bit or 64bit?

Tags: build, operating-system, continuous-integration

Greeting all,

I am at a point deciding which bit version to go for and am keen to hear your advice on this.

We have been running our build automation on a Windows 2003 32bit server with NAnt and CruiseControl.NET, and others including Visual Studio and relevant toolsets. As we are now looking into building for web applications which require IIS7, I consider to set up a new build environment in Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit.

However when I test run build automation on my Windows 7 64bit machine, I bum in many glitches relating %programfile%, e.g. checked out projects look for MS SDKs\Bootstrapper\Engine under the wrong %programfile%. I googled for solution and some of them require changes to project file - which I am not sure if appropriate as it likely affects how other developers build project on their dev environment.

So now I am thinking maybe I should have Windows Server 2008 32bits instead as I am not sure how many more of these compatibility issues I'd bum in - they can be quite a time waster. Is my suspicion on this correct? Should I stay with 32bit to be safe/ for a easier setup? Would it be sustainable having a 32bit CI server?

Much appreciated if you can comment on this and let me know your experience regarding an OS upgrade on a CI server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So after days of effort on this I've decided to re-configure CI on a 32 bit machine due to this showstopper I've bumped in.

**1. (Showstopper) cannot build silverlight project running msbuild.**

I receive the following error when msbuilding a csproj:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v3.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.Common.targets(101,9):
>   error : The Silverlight 3 SDK is not installed.
>   [SilverlightApplication1.csproj]

Though the recommended solution is to use the 32-bit MSBuild and target x86 or AnyCPU platforms to build your Silverlight projects according to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/05/07/building-on-cross-targeting-scenarios-and-64-bit-msbuild.aspx, I cannot get it working by loading 32bit msbuild from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 and set in NAnt:

```
<msbuild project="${SilverlightApplication1.csproj}">
         <property name="PlatformTarget" value="x86"/>
</msbuild>
```

Comment: After digging around, I realise that if I run <exec> with a specified x86 msbuild, I will not have this issue anymore. However I wonder where the NAnt <msbuild> points to..